# How to deal with interaction term's VIF score

Tags: regression, interaction, multicollinearity, variance-inflation-factor

I have a linear regression model that has no multicolinearity problem with low VIF scores. 
However, when I include the interaction term, this interaction term and its components get very high VIF scores. 
Can I ignore the multicolinearity problem and high VIF scores of the interaction term in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is yes. Interaction terms tend to be collinear with the original variables involved. That is why post-hoc interaction tests are often underpowered.

Interaction that is unaccounted for renders the estimate wrong, while inflated variance inflates p-value. If the interaction terms are already statistically significant, inflation of variance is no longer a problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Then reversely, if the interaction terms are not statistically significant, the VIF is a problem?

Comment: If the interaction terms are not significant then the reduced model with the interaction term is usually preferred. For that reason VIF became irrelevant.